Autocad key plan advice
I have an issue with a lot of the drawings I receive from my drawing office. The problem is that the drawings are relatively large, around 5 mb once PDF'd, and take quite a while to open, especially on site with a mobile device.
I would understand if this was due to a large amount of detail in the drawing, but it is not. Its due to the key plan. Deleting the key plan in a pdf editor reduces the file size to a few hundred kb making it much more manageable to work with.
the key plan is a viewport of the plant in modelspace. The issue is more the level of detail. For instance If I zoom in on the key plan on the PDF I can even see pressure indicators and other small details which I dont think is necessary on a key plan.
Is this the normal approach for creating a key plan and is there a simple way to reduce the mount of detail in the viewport. I assume they can create a simplified model of the site to use in the keyplan, but I am interested to see if there other easier ways to limit the detail shown in a viewport.

One controls what components are shown or suppressed. There may also additional optimizations that can be made to remove small entities on a pdf.  One example is that printing the pdf to paper will remove things smaller than the dpi of the printer, produce a medium unaffected by solar glare, and with the more deterministic load time of bringing out a piece of paper.
